# Default route inaccessible

Tags: angular, typescript

My application has the following structure:

**app.module.ts**

```
    const routes: Routes = [
      { path: '', loadChildren: './modules/main/main.module#MainModule' },
    ];

    @NgModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent,
      ],
      imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot(routes),
      ],
      providers: [
        AuthService,
        UtilService,
        UserService
      ],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })

    export class AppModule {
    }
```

**main.module.ts**

```
    @NgModule({
      declarations: [
        PressComponent,
        LegalComponent
      ],
      providers: [
        AuthService
      ],
      imports: [
        HomeModule,
        MainRoutingModule,
      ]
    })

    export class MainModule {
    }
```

**main.routing.component.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AnonymousGuard] },
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AnonymousGuard] },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '', pathMatch: 'full' }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class MainRoutingModule implements OnInit {
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { scrollPositionRestoration: 'enabled' });
  }
}
```

For some reason browsing to `/home` works but `/` doesn't. How can I fix this?

Comment: try `{path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full'}`
`{path: '**', component: HomeComponent} `

Comment: It re-directs to `/home` but I would like it to redirect to `/`.

Comment: `{ path: '', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AnonymousGuard], pathMatch: 'full' }`
`{path: '**', component: HomeComponent, redirectTo: ''}`

Comment: It doesn't work at `http://localhost:4200` as per https://pastebin.com/ZiQazh3t, but it works at `http://localhost:4200/home` when I add `{ path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AnonymousGuard] }`, I'd like it to work at `http://localhost:4200/` not `http://localhost:4200/home`.

Comment: `{ path: '',
        children: [
            { path: '', component: HomeComponent},
            { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent},
        ] }`

Comment: Reroutes to `/home` on load, its there a way to make it display HomeComponent at `/`.

Comment: have u added pathMatch to `''`

Comment: @methuselah - You mean that you want to have this ``http://localhost:4200`` or ``http://localhost:4200/``

Comment: I tried in my local machine everything works fine(with angular 8). the only thing that I changed is add ``pathMatch:'full'`` in this line ``{ path: '', component: HomeComponent, pathMatch:"full" }``

Answer (score 0):

Have you given base href as below in your index.html